# When are React ref callbacks supposed to run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the docs it says on mount, unmount. But I am seeing them being called everytime the owner receives props.

```
<A>
  <B ref={(component) => console.log(blah)}>
  </B>
<A>
```

Can anyone confirm the expected behavior?

My only other idea is that another HOC is interfering. I am using `react-dnd` which does wrap the ref callback.

The code for refs is at the linke below but I can't seem to work it out.

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/38acadf6f493926383aec0362617b8507ddee0d8/src/renderers/shared/reconciler/ReactRef.js

Answer (score 0):

I assume they run on `render`, because you don't have the DOM reference until then.